# Why is this bool changing?

Tags: c++, arduino

Without posting the entire source code for this, can anyone see why this `bool` is changing values?

```
const int redLed = 31;
const int greenLed =  33;
const int blueLed = 35;
const int irSensor = 2;
const int doorRelayPin = 14;
bool isDenied = false;
byte inputCard[4];
char cardID[4];
char passCode[10];
int passCount = 0;
char masterCode[10] = "1";

void loop(){
    if(isPanic){
      panicCounter++;
      int interval = panicCounter % 2000;
      Serial.println(interval);
      if (interval == 0){
        tryPost();
      }
   }else{
      if (!digitalRead(doorRelayPin) && !isDenied){
        greenSolid();
      }else if(digitalRead(doorRelayPin) && !isDenied){
        blueSolid();
        t.stop(unlock);
      }
   }
   Serial.print("isDenied bool: ");
   Serial.println(isDenied);
}
```

And the next bit of relevant code to help you understand the output...

```
Serial.println(F("Scanned PICC's UID on reader 1:"));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  //
  inputCard[i] = idReader.uid.uidByte[i];
  Serial.print(inputCard[i], HEX);
}
Serial.println("");
idReader.PICC_HaltA(); // Stop reading
getCardID();    // Get data ready
return 1;
```

As you can see i am not changing the value of this boolean ANYWHERE, but the serial output and my `if statement` in the loop function is saying the value has changed.  It seems to be happening during the PICC function while reading and RFID card.  Please advise, thanks!

Serial output below.

```
isDenied bool: 0
isDenied bool: 0
isDenied bool: 0
isDenied bool: 0
isDenied bool: 0
isDenied bool: 0
Scanned PICC's UID on reader 1:
F539A76B
isDenied bool: 54
ip=10.10.1.50&passcode=&rfid=f539a76b
connecting...Connected
disconnecting.
grant 10.10.1.50
Access Granted.
isDenied bool: 54
isDenied bool: 54
isDenied bool: 54
isDenied bool: 54
isDenied bool: 54
isDenied bool: 54
```

To make it even more odd, if i try to "hack" this problem by doing this in the loop function right above the `if(isPanic)` statement, the bool never changes.  BUT these new if statements are never satisfied either, the output log does not show either of those two test `Serial.println`'s

```
if (isDenied == 54){
  isDeniedBoolRecoverCounter++;
  Serial.println("In this");
}
if (isDeniedBoolRecoverCounter > 10){
   Serial.println("In the other one");
   isDenied = false;
   isDeniedBoolRecoverCounter = 0;
}
```

Comment: And you don't have any assignment to `isDenied` anywhere? What about variables surrounding `isDenied`? Are there arrays? Do you maybe write out of bounds of some array? Use a pointer that isn't properly initialized?

Comment: Negative.  What you're looking at is what you see.  I mean there is much more code, but i've searched many times through all classes and `isDenied` is not assigned anywhere else during that function.  And besides that, when i set it to true, the value is `1` anyway, not 54...

Comment: Two possible reasons: 1) One of the functions that gets called changes isDenied. I mean, if it never gets changed anywhere ever, then why have it in the first place? 2) As Joachim says, improperly initialized array/pointer, possibly from the reading function...

Comment: What do you mean by improperly initialized pointer?  Could you elaborate where you are going with that

Comment: A pointer is a variable whose content is an address in memory, they pop up a lot when you work with hardware. The problem is that if you don't use them correctly, you can easily mess up with other memory parts of your  program and, e.g., overwrite variables you had declared elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have any pointers? Where do you make them point? How do you initialize them? You don't use the pointers before they are initialized? Do you use any array-indexing, with arrays or with pointers? Do you possibly go out of bounds there?

Comment: I added to the questions showing the declarations surrounding `isDenied`

Comment: Check your code an see if there is anywhere you could access `inputCard[-1]`.  Also if you are always getting 54 then try and see if there is an assignment to 54 somewhere.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup *As you can see i am not changing the value of this boolean ANYWHERE* -- Two words -- **buffer overrun**.  When you see variables change mysteriously, this is an indication that you are stomping on those variables due to overrunning an array's boundaries or similar issue.

Comment: To clarify, i DO change the value, but no where in the snippets i provided. And somewhere in this is where the problem has to lie if you look at the serial output.  The only function called at the time that bool changes values, is `getCardId()`, and that is one line of code that does not contain `isDenied`.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, there is no assignment to 54 nor is there reference to `inputCard[-1]`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What is the best way to debug that and trace down where the problem may lie?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup If you have UB in your code it does not matter.  You need to make sure there is no UB,  Better yet make a [mcve] and see if you can replicate the behavior.  If you cannot then you know the problem is elsewhere.  You may want to see: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @NathanOliver See the addition i just made to the end of this question.  How is any of that possible?  And what is UB?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup -- The best way to debug it is to set a watch point that halts your program when that variable changes.  Any good debugger has such facilities.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup UB == Undefined behavior.  Once you code undefined behavior all bets are off on what the program will do.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of work with arduinos, but debuggers often have the ability to set breakpoints on a change of data at an address. If were to set a breakpoint on the variable that is mysteriously changing, you would be able to find the location

Comment: Yes, i'm familiar with breakpoints and debugging in Visual Studio and Xcode, however, the Arduino IDE does not have any debugging tools like that.  It compiles and uploads this code to the Arduino and it's gone, the only thing attached to it is the serial monitor.

Comment: Writing independently testable code has many virtues. This is one of them...

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup - You can debug remotely in Visual Studio (code on remote machine, debug on develepment machine).  Second, if you are familiar with debugging, the watchpoint is the way to solve your issue.  So this really boils down to getting the Visual Studio debugging set up for your environment.

Comment: Adding this to the beginning of the `loop` function solves the issue, and makes zero sense to me... i'm literally not doing anything except for referencing the variable. `if (isDenied == 54){ Serial.println("IT'S 54.  BREAK CODE"); delay(10000000);}`  And by "solves" i mean it does not change the value unexpectedly anymore, it stays at 0.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup --Nooooo.  Don't change the code!  You are just moving the bug to another part of the code.  Leave the code alone and actually fix the issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup That doesn't really surprise me. A program with undefined behavior often behaves (strangely enough) in undefined ways.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup -- You are adding code that does basically nothing, and then things magically "work".  This is an indication that your code is the realm of undefined behavior.  Remove the code you just wrote, bring back the error, and actually fix the problem by identifying *why* the issue occurs.  Otherwise you will be running a program that has a hidden bug that could arise at any time, either when the program runs, or when you add or remove code and rebuild your application.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes i agree, i am just trying different things to diagnose the issue and hopefully pinpoint the issue.  I will just try and get this attached to a debugger and go from there.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: If you can't get it to run in a debugger, your only real option is to comb the code looking for "bad stuff", so I hope you can get remote debugging working.

Comment: I found the issue.  Can anyone answer these questions so i might learn something from this? 1) Can anyone explain why the value i was seeing in the boolean was 54?  

2) Why is that the `isDenied` variable was being changed instead of another one?

3) Why did declaring `char cardID[] = "";`" not work the same as statically setting the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you guys were correct. It was a buffer overrun issue pertaining to the `cardID[]` variable.  Originally it was initialized as `cardID[4] = "";`  After narrowing it down to confirming that is the issue, i tried `cardID[] = "";` which did resolve the issue, however the `isDenied` bool was still being changed momentarily, although it reverted back correctly.  The final correct declaration was `char cardID[8] = "";`

I'm still wrapping my head around the char array variables and how they should be declared/initialized.

My guess is i was trying to assign "f539a76b" to a (4) character char array with the line...

```
sprintf(cardID, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", inputCard[0], inputCard[1], inputCard[2], inputCard[3]);
```

When in fact i needed a (8) character array.

Comment: Answers are not an appropriate place to ask further questions. Consider appending these additional questions to your existing question, or opening up more questions when appropriate.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup -- If you're going to use char arrays to be used as buffers for `sprintf`, the last thing you want to do is try and compute, down to the last byte, how big to make the array.  That method is doomed for failure at some point.  Make the array bigger than what you would have expected (and even that isn't a great solution).  The best solution would be to use `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: This is Arduino, not complete C++ so I don't have access to all the standard C operators.